# Which version of d3dx should I install? (WINE)

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install directx9 in order to play some old games on Linux, and I'm using winetricks to help me do so. My understanding is that I need to install the "d3dx" library. But In the winetricks gui I get several versions (d3dx9_24 to d3dx9_43) plus one that is simply labeled "d3dx" with the title "d3dx_??.dll". First of all, Am I even doing this right? If so, which version should I install?

Comment: I think it depends on the game, you could search online for game specifics. WineHQ is a good start.. but you can also try the latest version. and check if it works :)